# AlertDialog com background

Tags: java, android, alertdialog

Criei este alertDialog mas gostava de saber se em vez de ter um icon quando ele aparece, se e possível todo ele ter outra cor ou mesmo usar uma imagem como seu (Background).E Atribuir aos botões uma background.

```
public void icon (View View){
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder (this);
        dialog.setMessage("Exemplo com icon");
        dialog.setPositiveButton("NEXT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                setContentView(R.layout.next);
            }
        });
        dialog.setTitle("Icone");
        dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.buttonum);
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar um layout.xml e adicional ao AlertDialog

```
final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(suaActivity.this)
                    .setView(R.layout.seulayout)
                    .create();
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Mas continuo com um problema. No layout que criei tem um botao e quando carrego ele abre outro layout mas nao fecha o alertdialog

Comment: usa dialog.dismiss quando quiser fechar

Comment: Muito obrigado Icaro ;)